# What SSL certificate should I use if I'm reverse proxying a subdomain?

Tags: ssl, iis

Our company has a blog as a subdomain, but we'd like it to be on a subfolder at www.domain.com/blog instead. We had this in the recent past by using ApplicationRequestRouting on IIS to set up a reverse proxy - any request for /blog would reverse proxy blog.domain.com which worked well.

However, that recently stopped working - most likely when an SSL certificate on one (or both) of the subdomain and main domain was updated. Now requests for domain.com/blog displays a 502 bad gateway error, although the subdomain works fine.

Could the issue be that the main domain needs to have a wildcard SSL certificate that covers it's use for all subdomains too?

Comment: Are the 2 sites on the same or different servers?

Comment: They're on different servers